# How to use the software autojump in Emacs's minibuffer?

Tags: emacs, command-line

How to use the software autojump in Emacs's minibuffer?

I like using [autojump](https://github.com/joelthelion/autojump/wiki) at command line to save time navigating between paths. I feel needing the same convenience in the Emacs minibuffer when I am editting different files. How to achieve this?

[Edit]

The alternative approach I am currently using is to invoke `shell` mode in a Emacs buffer and use autojump in that shell-in-Emacs-buffer. Or just turn to the shell program (Terminal, iTerm, etc.) and run autojump there. Then copy the path I found using autojump into Emacs minibuffer.

Comment: Yuo should add more detail to the question, so we know why the offered solutions which enable you to jump to any file in the file system by typing a few characters are not suitable. How is what you want different from that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use the list of recent file names for file name completion. [This page](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RecentFiles) explains how you can do this and lists several completion packages.

From my experience I recommend Iswitchb completion or Anything completion from the listed alternatives.

Update: [here is an other page from Emacswiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LocateFilesAnywhere) which describes how you can get to anywhere in your filesystem quickly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with autojump, but I followed your link and read the description.  "Maintaining a database of the directories you use the most" sounds like overkill for minibuffer completion, but I'm sure you could write some code to incorporate such an existing database.

I'd suggest just one of these approaches:

- Rely on the minibuffer (file-name/dir-name) history.  But use a completion package that lets you easily get to whatever you want in the history.  If you want persistence then automatically save the history using `savehist.el'.
- Use Emacs ***bookmarks*** -- bookmark some Dired buffers that are important to you.  If you use [***Icicles***](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_File-Name_Input#icicle-bookmark-file-other-window) and [***Bookmark+***](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus) then file and directory (Dired) bookmarks are available as candidates whenever you use file-name completion -- just hit <kbd>C-x m</kbd> to complete against the bookmark names.

Comment: Auto completion and access history approaches doesn't solve the problem of having to repeatedly typing long prefix of paths, which is exactly what autojump solves. So I consider Drew and Tom's suggestions not best solutions. But thanks any way.

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding here. Completion is exactly for avoding typing long paths. You can type only a few characters and you can get to anywhere in your file system.

Comment: I don't think there is any misunderstanding. With autocomplete, one always have to type in a long enough *prefix* to autocomplete it to a unique full path. With autojump, one does not have to type in a long enough *prefix* but any long enough *part* of the full path is sufficient.

Comment: With [Icicles](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/Icicles) you can use other kinds of completion (e.g. regexp) than prefix completion. And you can also (alternatively) complete against absolute file names (any parts of the path).  And you can set up sets of paths (like projects) to complete against.